# How do you get the language from a session in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have some code that sets the lang var to the site default language.

```
$lg = &JFactory::getLanguage();
$lg = explode('-',$lg->_default);
$dlg = $lg[0];
if(!JRequest::getWord('lang', false ))
    JRequest::setVar('lang', $dlg );
```

however before setting it to $dlg I would like to find out if the language is stored in the user information or session.

Can someone tell me how to check the session for language information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lg = &JFactory::getLanguage();
$lg = explode('-',$lg->_lang);
$dlg = $lg[0];
if(!JRequest::getWord('lang', false ))
    JRequest::setVar('lang', $dlg );
```

i had to just change it from _default to _lang